# How to prevent users from entering and copying any non-ascii characters in html input box using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text box to enter something. I want to allow users to enter All the characters which are ASCII. I don't want users even to copy the characters which are not ascii. How to do that using jquery and simple javascript. @#$ etc are allowed because they are ascii. No copy or enter by keyboard.

Comment: @#$ are ascii, perhaps you meant alpha-numeric?

Comment: I mean the user only allow to enter/copy ascii characters nothing else

Comment: but the characters you listed, `@#$` are all ascii characters

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You could remove characters, though, upon submit at the latest. BTW—HTML characters are Unicode (using the UTF-16 encoding in JavaScript) It seems the subset you want to allow is the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block.

Answer (score 2):

if you mean only alphanumeric values this will work:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" onChange="checkInput(this)" onKeyUp="checkInput(this)" />

<script type="text/javascript">

  function checkInput(f){
    var field = $(f);
    field.val(field.val().replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,''));
  }
</script>
```

notice I use `onChange()` and `onKeyUp()` that is to catch pasted and typed values.

Comment: Hm.. I don't think native JS has any `.val()` method.

Comment: jQuery was in the question and a `tag` @Mikey I was using this implementation. http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2

Comment: Then you probably want `$(field)` instead of `field`.

Comment: funny thing is, I gave the input tag an `id` and decided to pass an argument instead, but left the unused `id` in there.

Comment: The Change and KeyUp events cover most cases very soon after input. Here's an odd case though: Running this snippet on Windows Desktop Chrome, Alt+0151 (m-dash) doesn't fire those either of events until there some other interaction like additional keys or lost focus.

Comment: @TomBlodget that is something I didnt know.  do you know an event that would catch those?  For OPs case, loss of focus may be enough, but it is an interesting `corner-case`

Comment: I am always suspicious of my understanding of when events fire. I just discovered it by chance using your snippet so I don't know if any other events fire. It's definitely a corner case; one that wouldn't impact typical web applications.